# I need to create a function that will return number of day in a week on requested date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Something like this (which is not working)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek 
     (@b_date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @weekday VARCHAR(10)

    IF (SELECT DATENAME(dw, @b_date) 
        RETURN (@weekday)
END;
GO
```

after using this

```
SELECT dbo.udf_DayOfWeek ('May 22, 2016');
GO
```

to return value of 1-7(number of a day in week)

I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Are you looking for `DATEPART(DW, 'May 22, 2016')` to be your return value?

Comment: Not sure, tried, not working. SELECT dbo.udf_DayOfWeek ('May 22, 2016');
GO this one is a must, code before is that I cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use `DATEPART()` versus `DATENAME()` to get the numeric value, but this can be done inline and really doesn't need it's own function.

```
SELECT DATEPART(weekday,'May 22, 2016')
```

And to fix your function syntax...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek (@b_date DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @weekday INT
    SELECT @weekday = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @b_date) 
    RETURN (@weekday)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

DatePart for weekday uses the DateFirst setting, making it difficult to use consistently.  The problem is, some places in the world consider Sunday to be the first day of the week, and other places consider Monday to be the first day of the week.  Because of this ambiguity, SQL Server will use the datefirst setting of the login currently connected to the database.  To see a list of datefirst settings, run this:

```
Select * From sys.syslanguages
```

You can manually set the DateFirst value that persists for the duration of the connection like this:

```
Set DateFirst 1
SELECT DATEPART(weekday,'May 22, 2016')

Set DateFirst 7
SELECT DATEPART(weekday,'May 22, 2016')
```

Note that the output of the previous code changes depending on the DateFirst setting.

If you want 1 to always represent Sunday, regardless of the user's language setting, you can use this:

```
Select DateDiff(Day, 6,@DateVariable) % 7 + 1
```

Using this information, you can create your user defined function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek 
     (@b_date DATETIME)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    return (
        Select DateDiff(Day, 6,@b_date) % 7 + 1
    )
END;
```